# Comparing two string variables with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list control on a page and there are three items that should any of these be selected then they need to invoke a special condition. I have tried using if statements and the == operators but the code now seems to be stuck and not working correctly.The user will select from the drop down list item that is not any of the below but it will still treat it as if it where == to the first if condition. I dont know what seems to be the problem with this please if any one could help.Thanks in advance...

```
       if (lbl_status.Text.ToString() == "item 1" || lbl_status.Text.ToString() == "item 2" || lbl_status.Text.ToString() != "item 3")
                {
                    lb_Warning.Visible = true;
                    lb_Warning.Text = " testing";
                }
                else if (lbl_status.Text.ToString() != "item 1" || lbl_status.Text.ToString() != "item 2" || lbl_status.Text.ToString() != "item 3")
                { }
```

Comment: It would help if you'd post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Additionally: 1) use a local variable for `lbl_status.Text.ToString()` to vastyl improve readability. 2) your `else if` condition doesn't do what you think it does. (It's not clear what you're really trying to achieve, but it's pointless because the value will always *either* be not equal to "item 1" *or* be not equal to "item 2".)

Comment: are your sure you want a `!=` for `item 3` in the first line ? By the way, I would use an array of desired / undesired values... And in second test, you need `&&`, not `||`

Comment: Indeed - any value other than "item 3" will execute the body of the `if` statement...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the conditions with the value of the dropdownlist rather than the text

```
if(lbl_status.SelectedValue = )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else if will only be true if its neither value1, value2 nor value3... is that supposed to be like that?
Try this

```
if (lbl_status.Text.ToString() == "item 1" || lbl_status.Text.ToString() == "item 2" || lbl_status.Text.ToString() != "item 3")
{
    lb_Warning.Visible = true;
    lb_Warning.Text = " testing";
}
else if (lbl_status.Text.ToString() != "item 1" || lbl_status.Text.ToString() != "item 2" || lbl_status.Text.ToString() == "item 3")
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

`C#` string comparison is case sensitive, for example, `"Abc" == "abc" // false`

To compare ignoring case sensitivity, try this:

```
string.Compare("Abc", "abc", true) == 0 // if 0, the strings are the same
```

Also, make sure you don't have white spaces at beginning / end, use `"string".Trim()` to remove them

Answer (score 0):

Try to refator a bit, they are a few strange things (mentionned in my comment above), and this will help to avoid them...

```
//first, create an array of used values, it will makes things clearer
var items = new[]{"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};

//check if the selected value is in the array
if (items.Contains(lbl_status.SelectedValue)) {
    lb_Warning.Visible = true;
    lb_Warning.Text = " testing";
}
//if the selected value is not in the array, you will enter else
else {
    ----
}
```